# Create a function which returns the number of true values there are in an array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

The code compiles but always returns 0. When I read the code out it makes sense that it should work; I've spent a while troubleshooting, not sure why it isn't working.

```
public class Challenge {
   public static int countTrue(boolean[] arr) {
     // declaring the variable to return
      int amountTrue = 0;
    // for each to loop through the array
    for (boolean i : arr) {
        // if array item == true add 1 to variable amountTrue, if false, add 0 to amountTrue
        if (arr.equals(true)) {
          return amountTrue++;
        } else {
          return amountTrue + 0;
        }} 
      // returning the variable 
       return amountTrue; }}
```

I am expecting the function to count all the trues in the array. I have tried both a for loop and for each loop.

Comment: Don't `return` inside the loop

Comment: A `boolean[]` will never be `true`, so review your condition in `if (arr.equals(true))`…

Comment: You're comparing the array `arr` to `true` instead of the value `i`. That's all.

Comment: @Jorn I stand corrected.

Comment: replace the if else statement to `if (i) { amountTrue++;  }`

Comment: Compare the item `i` in the array instead of the whole array. Don't `return` inside the loop, just increment the counter if the condition is met and return the counter after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks for everyone's help, really appreciate the community.

Picked up a few good bits from here like not returning in a loop, whereas, I think the concept of autoboxing is way out of my league atm (but do know not to use .equals() with primitives now).

I solved the issue with this with the help of your advice:

```
    public static int countTrue(boolean[] arr) {
        int amountTrue = 0;
        for (boolean i : arr){ 
            if (i == true) {
                amountTrue+=1;
            }} return amountTrue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is curious, I am doing coding challenges on edabit website.

Comment: there is no need to compare any boolean expression to `true` (`i == true` is the same as just `i`)

Comment: And get into the habit of properly formatting your code. It will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. You should not return inside the loop, also you were testing the array for true and not the element i, which will always return false, hence you always got zero

```
  public class Challenge {
    public static int countTrue(boolean[] arr) {
        // declaring the variable to return
        int amountTrue = 0;
        // for each to loop through the array
        for (boolean i : arr) {
            // if array item == true add 1 to variable amountTrue
            // if false do nothing
            if (i.equals(true)) {
                amountTrue += 1;
            }
        }
        // returning the variable 
        return amountTrue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare primitives with `equals()`. It causes needless autoboxing.

Comment: `if (i.equals(true)` is doing a lot of unnecessary:  (1) auto-boxing `i` from `boolean` to `Boolean`; (2) *converting* (done by compiler) the operand `true` to `Boolean.TRUE`; (3) calling the `equals` method... to compare primitives we should use `==`; (4) comparing against `true` or `Boolean.TRUE` (there is no need to compare any boolean expression (e.g. `i`) to `true` {`x == true` is the same as just `x`} )

Comment: actually, does it compile? Can we call a method from a primitive? Forget the previous comment, there will be no auto-boxing but a compilation error (and upvoted two times....)

Comment: @user85421 You're right. Doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

in the cycle for only write this:

```
if (i == true) {
   amountTree++;
}
```

without the else, and at the end simply return amountTree, in your code you check if the Object arr is equals to boolean true,but arr is an array, you have to check the i element that are boolean, you haven't to use the return in the cycle because this stop your code and at the end have no sense (add 0 if i != true), you can only add 1 if (i element == true)

Comment: here is no need to compare any boolean expression (e.g. `i`) to `true` {`x == true` is the same as just `x` for any expression `x`}

Comment: if the input is a list of boolean value you have to check every item == true for add 1 to amountTree

Comment: `if (i == true)` is better written as `if (i)`  !!

Comment: yeah of course but i think that for understand the initial errors is better write the extensive code

Comment: by that logic, you should also have written `amountTree = amountTree + 1;`  and so on... I believe, for learning, it is better to also show the *conventional* way (according best practices) - so I added the comment, also for other readers, not just the question's author

Comment: the author of the question had written amountTree ++ in his code, so it made no sense to write amountTree = amountTree+1, I think it is more important to show the main errors than to focus on some practices, and I also believe that sometimes it is better to write slightly longer code but which is better understood, without exaggerating obviously, we rely on common sense, I understand your intent perfectly, I just don't agree with focusing on things that can be considered subjective, in any case everyone has the right to think as he wants